# Do Aichelburg-Sexl spacetime give excitation to a string?

Tags: astrophysics, string-field-theory

I read about an article stating the excitation of a charged string passing through a shockwave in the Aichelburg-Sexl spacetime, how does it excites the string?

Comment: [This article](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0007210)?

Comment: yep...that one...